# PyCharm Reuploads helpers each reboot

Tags: pycharm

I have PyCharm pro 5.0.4, since the release of version 4, each time I reboot PyCharm, and after doing an action that needs to connect to my remote interpreter (right click, opening the project interpreter settings... etc), it starts uploading (again) the PyCharm helpers to my remote server (popup in the middle of the screen that you can't dismiss).

Any ideas what is causing this issue and how to fix it ?!